# Proving a Markov chain has a stationary measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, markov-chains, riesz-representation-theorem

I'm in a measure-theoretic probability class and I am studying for an upcoming exam. Here is a problem from a book that I am studying from for this exam. But I am really not sure how to solve this problem since I am new to weak measures and representations.

> Consider a Markov transition function $P$ on a compact space $X$.
>   Prove that the corresponding Markov chain has at least one stationary
>   measure.

I am given the following hint:

> (Hint: Take an arbitrary initial measure $\mu$ and define
>   $\mu_n = (P^{*})^{n}\mu, n \geq 0$. Prove that the sequence of
>   measures defined by $\eta_n = (\mu_0 + \cdots + \mu_{n-1})/n$ is weakly
>   compact and the limit of a subsequence is a stationary measure.)

I am familiar with  many theorems, like Prokhorov Theorem, Riesz Representation Theorem, and more. But I'm really not sure how to solve this problem. I will really appreciate any help.

I found these notes (whose source is completely unrelated to the source of the problem) online, and they have been helpful to me: https://www.math.wisc.edu/~roch/grad-prob/gradprob-notes22.pdf

But I still cannot solve the problem.

Comment: So what does Prokhorov's theorem tell you about the set of probability measures on $X$?

Comment: So is the collection of prob. measures on $X$ tight?

Comment: Take as $K_\epsilon$  your $X$: it is compact, and you know its probability.

Comment: I did not realize that. Okay, now I agree that the collection of probability measures on $X$ is tight, so by Prokhorov's Theorem, it's weakly compact

Comment: I'm still not able to make much progress on this. Could you please help me? @kimchilover

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal P(X)$ denote the space whose elements are Borel probability measures on $X$, with the topology of weak convergence of measures. A special case of Prokhorov's Theorem implies that when $X$ is compact, this space $\mathcal P(X)$ is also compact. In particular, all infinite sequences in $\mathcal P(X)$ [possess a limit point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point_compact).

You have an infinite sequence in $\mathcal P(X)$, thus existence of a limit point means that there is a probability measure $\mu\in\mathcal P(X)$ such that some subsequence of the sequence you have written converges weakly to $\mu$.

Now fix any open set $A\subseteq X$ and consider $\mu(A)-P^*\mu(A)$. Let $\{n_k\}$ denote the convergent subsequence. Observe how
$$
|\mu(A)-P^*\mu(A)|=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{|\mu_0(A)-\mu_{n_k}(A)|}{n_k}=0,
$$
since the difference of measures telescopes and $|\mu_0(A)-\mu_{n_k}(A)|\leq 1$.